# How do VS code and the debugger for Chrome to display my current code in a google page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, web, localhost

Hello I'm getting started in VS code.  I'm taking a Udemy course about Javascript, I'm glad I've found VS code.  I added the Debugger for Chrome. In the drop down box it says Launch with Chrome. But, when my MAC loads the webpage, it says 'can not connect to local host8080'.  How do I fix this so I can see how my code displays in a Google Chrome browser?

Comment: You can use live server plugin for vscode

Comment: I installed a live server but it's still giving me the can not connect to localhost when my computer attempts to open a web browser in google chrome

Comment: Maybe the port is busy, you can try to connect to another port of instead give more details about your setup for search for other possibles errors.

Comment: ok thanks I got it, I think